# Wix !(bind.AssemblyFullName.fileId) only works on GACed assemblies?

Tags: .net, com, installation, wix, registry

Woe, woe and thrice woe. Why does Wix make installing .NET assemblies SOOOOOO difficult!

I'm installing a COM Inprocess Server which is implemented in .NET, in my Wix install I need to create the registry entries for it. I don't WANT to do this, I'd rather Wix had an equivalent of RegAsm, but they make me do this manually. I got tired of getting flamed for suggesting this was a tad arcane, so I gave up and tried to do it the declarative way, like a good boy. So, here's what my registry stuff looks like now:

```
<File Id="filDriverAssembly" Source="$(var.TiGra.Astronomy.AWRDriveSystem.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" Assembly=".net">
  <!--<Class Context="InprocServer32" Description="$(var.InstallName)" Id ="$(var.DriverGuid)" ThreadingModel ="both" >
    <ProgId Description="$(var.InstallName)" Id ="$(var.DriverId)" />
  </Class>-->
</File>
<RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="$(var.DriverId)"  Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
  <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="$(var.DriverTypeName)"/>
  <RegistryKey Key="CLSID">
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="$(var.DriverGuid)" />
    <RegistryKey Key="$(var.DriverGuid)">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="$(var.DriverTypeName)"/>
      <RegistryKey Key="InprocServer32">
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="mscoree.dll" />
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ThreadingModel" Value="Both"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="$(var.DriverTypeName)"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Assembly" Value="!(bind.AssemblyFullName.filDriverAssembly)"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="2.0.50727"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#filDriverAssembly]" />
        <RegistryKey Key="!(bind.fileVersion.filDriverAssembly)" >
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="$(var.DriverTypeName)"/>
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Assembly" Value="!(bind.AssemblyFullName.filDriverAssembly)"/>
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="2.0.50727"/>
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#filDriverAssembly]" />
        </RegistryKey>
      </RegistryKey>
      <RegistryKey Key="ProgId">
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="$(var.DriverId)" />
      </RegistryKey>
      <RegistryKey Key="Implemented Categories">
        <RegistryKey Key="{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" />
      </RegistryKey>
    </RegistryKey>
  </RegistryKey>
</RegistryKey>
<!-- Wow6432Node for x86 compatibility, installed only on x64 systems -->
<!-- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node -->
<?if $(var.Win64) = "yes" ?>
<RegistryKey Root="HKCR" Key="Wow6432Node" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
  <RegistryKey Key="CLSID">
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="$(var.DriverGuid)" />
    <RegistryKey Key="$(var.DriverGuid)">
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="$(var.DriverTypeName)"/>
      <RegistryKey Key="InprocServer32">
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="mscoree.dll" />
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ThreadingModel" Value="Both"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="$(var.DriverTypeName)"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Assembly" Value="!(bind.AssemblyFullName.filDriverAssembly)"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="2.0.50727"/>
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#filDriverAssembly]" />
        <RegistryKey Key="!(bind.assemblyVersion.filDriverAssembly)" >
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Class" Value="$(var.DriverTypeName)"/>
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Assembly" Value="!(bind.AssemblyFullName.filDriverAssembly)"/>
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="2.0.50727"/>
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#filDriverAssembly]" />
        </RegistryKey>
      </RegistryKey>
      <RegistryKey Key="ProgId">
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="$(var.DriverId)" />
      </RegistryKey>
      <RegistryKey Key="Implemented Categories">
        <RegistryKey Key="{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" />
      </RegistryKey>
    </RegistryKey>
  </RegistryKey>
</RegistryKey>
<?endif ?>
```

RegAsm is for wimps, eh? Anyway, notice that I need to get the assembly full name to create some of the registry keys. I'm using binder variables, specifically, `Value="!(bind.AssemblyFullName.filDriverAssembly)"`.

This however, does not work unless I add the attribute `Assembly=".net"` to the file entry. If I don't add that attribute, or if I use `Assembly="no"`, then I get

> Error 2   Unresolved bind-time variable
>   !(bind.AssemblyFullName.filDriverAssembly).

When I add `Assembly=".net"` to the file item, then the binder variables work just fine, but Wix puts my assembly into the Global Assembly Cache, which is **NOT** what I want! Oh, man.

Is it not possible to query an assembly's full name in a Wix project if its not going into the GAC? Why do these two things depend on each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless a file is marked as an assembly, it's just like any other file; WiX has no idea it might have assembly attributes. Check out the AssemblyApplication attribute: You can set it to an appropriate file and set @Assembly=".net" without telling MSI the file goes into the GAC.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works from the documentation, could you provide an example? That attribute seems to be valid only on the NativeAssembly key, which would force NGEN to generate native assemblies. I don't want to NGEN the assembly; it's the same problem, everything has two meanings. I only want to get metadata from an assembly to use in another part of the installation process.

Comment: Also, my assembly is a general purpose item that will be loaded by many applications, some of which don't yet exist. How am I to specify "the application that will load this assembly"?

Comment: I'm talking about the File/@AssemblyApplication attribute.

Comment: ah ok, I see it. My problem is that I have _no application_ to specify. I'm installing a shared COM component. I guess I could fudge it somehow.

Comment: It works! I set the File/@AssemblyApplication to point back to itself, the file no longer gets GACed and now all the bind variables work. Result! (a bit of a hack though).